# How to use strtok to parse string at whitespace?

Tags: c, string

I am trying to use `strtok()` to parse a string deliminated by spaces. From what I can tell, I am using it correctly, but it won't run on ideone.com. Is there anything wrong with the following code? I just get `Runtime error     time: 0 memory: 2288 signal:11`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void test(char *command)
{
    char* output = strtok(command, " ");
    printf("%s\n", output);
}

int main(void) {

    test("set_rate 200");

    return 0;
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/R3hJ8f) it is on ideone.com if you want to try it.

Comment: Did you try it on your own computer?

Comment: I can't try it on my computer in my current development environment.

Comment: Destroying your input in order to produce output is really bad function design. I recommend never using strtok. There are plenty of [alternative examples out there](http://pjd-notes.blogspot.com/2011/09/alternative-to-strtok3-in-c.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtok` will modify the string passed as the first parameter, so you can't pass a string literal, change your `main` like this:

```
int main(void) {  
    char str[] = "set_rate 200";
    test(str);
    return 0;
}
```

`str` here is an `char` array, but not a string literal.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. I'm still fairly new to C. I thought that `char* str` and 'char[] str' were equivalent. Isn't a `char[]` just a pointer to a `char`? How are these different?

Comment: @unexpected62 By actually declaring the variable you are allocating a ram variable. By directly placing the string in the parameter it is compiled into something stored only ROM when using most C compilers.

Comment: @unexpected62 char s[] = "string"; creates a mutable string where s is a char array allocated with length of string + 1 bytes. char *s = "string", creates a string constant which is pointed to by s. You are free to modify the first s with [], but you cannot do so for the char *s. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Always consult the `man` pages first.

[`strtok(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) says:

> Be cautious when using these functions.  If you do use them, note that:
>
> - These functions modify their first argument.
> - These functions cannot be used on constant strings.

Answer (score 3):

As `strtok` modifies the string, it requires that the string is not in read-only memory. So when you pass a string literal to your test function, it crashes.

**This is better:**

```
char s[] = "set_rate 200";
test(s);
```

Comment: It may help to explain that in your modified code, the string is on the (read-write) stack of `main`, instead of a read-only section.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass hard coded string that was stored in read-only memory.

`strtok()` does not work with string which is read-only memory.

You need to use string variable rather than string literal .

you can first store string in some variable and then you can pass it to the function.

```
char[]="set_rate 200";
test(str);
```

See example:

```
 char *str = malloc(20);
    char *tok = NULL;
    int len = 0;

    strcpy(str, "This is a string");
    len = strlen(str);

    printf("string before strtok(): %s\n", str);
    tok = strtok(str, " ");
    while (tok) {
        printf("Token: %s\n", tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
```

**Edit**

From  @Yu Hao comment  i am adding this

```
char *str = "set_rate 200"; 
test(str); // This won't work. here str is pointer to the string literal.
```

Comment: Your first attempt is **wrong**. In `char *str = "set_rate 200";`, `str` is still a pointer to a string literal. The problem remains. The code in the comment is correct, and they are **not** the same.

Comment: Yes those both are not same.`*str` is pointer to string and `str[]` is char array.can you clarify a bit more here. why it is not working with `*str`

Comment: See [What is the difference between `char s[]` and `char *s` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Comment: Thanks. first lines of accepted answer are more than enough explanation.